# HEREMaps iOS: Zoom to specific point

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I need to zoom NMAMapView to specific point inside map bounds. Let's say we have some marker as subview of this map with position `pinPoint: CGPoint`.
I tried to use `transformCenter` property of NMAMapView like this:

```
let transformCenter = CGPoint(x: pinPoint.x / mapView.bounds.width, y: pinPoint.y / mapView.bounds.height) // x and y are in range [0, 1]
mapView.transformCenter = transformCenter
mapView.set(zoomLevel: mapView.zoomLevel + 1, animation: .linear)
```

But this code zooms map to its frame center, not to pinPoint.

I also tried to zoom map to needed point with code below:

```
guard let coordinates = mapView.geoCoordinates(from: pinPoint) else {
    return
}
mapView.set(coordinates: coordinates, to: pinPoint, animation: .linear, zoomLevel: mapView.zoomLevel + 1)
```

But this also doesn't work correctly: after zooming, geo coordinates below marker were changed after each zoom step.

Comment: Similar question has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513961/change-the-transformcenter-dynamically/54539473#54539473. Check if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to with this code, this code is just for your reference, You need to modify as per your requirements.

```
    // create geo coordinate
    let geoCoordCenter = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: 49.260327, longitude: -123.115025)
    // set map view with geo center
    self.mapView.set(geoCenter: geoCoordCenter, animation:NMAMapAnimation.none)
    // set zoom level
    self.mapView.zoomLevel = 13.2
```

Please check more example [GitHub](https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples).